# Application of Morse theory to second order systems

Tags: morse-theory, applications, ds.dynamical-systems

Hello

I'm looking for some applications of Morse theory to second order differential system,( or boundary value problems )

Someone can help me with a pdf or a book which has these applications  ?

Thank you

Comment: Milnor's book on Morse theory contains applications to a famous second order equations, namely the geodesci equations. Morse's original  motivation was  investigation  of geodescis.

Comment: this part :THE CALCULUS OF VARIATIONS APPLIED TO GEODESICS , from page 67 to 69 ?

Comment: @Liviu Nicolaescu : i read the from the page 67 to 69 and i don't find the system of second order 